# Existence of open ball in whole space from the existence of nonempty open set in subspace

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am reading some mathematical article but I don't understand one step in the proof. Assume that $(X,d)$ is a complete and separable metric space (maybe this is not important that the space is complete and separable, but I'm not sure) and assume that $A\subset X$ is open and nonempty. Define $Y:=cl A$ (closure of A in $(X,d)$) as a subspace of the space $(X,d)$ and assume that there exist a set $V\subset Y$ open in the space $Y$. We have to prove that there exist an open ball $B$ in the space $(X,d)$ such that $B\subset V$

Here you can find more details of my question. We know also that $$Y=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}Y_n$$ where $Y_n$ are closed in $Y$ and we know that there exist $N$ such that $int Y_N\neq \emptyset$ (interior in subspace $Y$) Then there exist a ball $B$ in the space $(X,d)$ such that $B\subset Y_N$. This is the right question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $V$ is an open of $Y$, it can be written $Y \cap U$ for an open $U$ of $X$. Then $U \cap A$ is an open of $X$ (non empty is $V$ is not empty), so contains a ball $B$ and finally $B \subset A \cap U \subset Y \cap U=V$.

Comment: (Assuming $V$ is not empty). You have omitted the step that shows that $U\cap A$ is a $non$-$empty$ open subset of $X:$ If  $U$ is open in $X$ and disjoint from $A$ then $U$ is disjoint from $Cl_X(A),$  implying $V=Y\cap U=Cl_X(A)\cap U=\emptyset. $

Answer (score 0):

The set $V$ is irrelevant ! Take $a \in A$. Since $A$ is open, there is an open ball $B$ such that $a \in B \subset A$. Hence $B \subset cl(A)=Y.$

Comment: I'm sorry, my question was not well-formed. I have edited my question.

Comment: I think  I should write $B\subset V$ instead of $B\subset Y$

Answer (score 0):

Is this not the definition of an open set ?

By definition, $\mathrm{Int}(Y_n)$ is an open set : if it is non-empty, there is a point $a \in \mathrm{Int}(Y_n)$, and by definition of an open set, you can find a ball (that contains $a$) contained in $\mathrm{Int}(Y_n)$, so contained in $Y_n$.

Comment: I'm sorry, my question was not well-formed. I have edited my question.

Comment: I think  I should write $B\subset V$ instead of $B\subset Y$

Comment: Ok, so I edit my answer ; but it is not more complicated !

Comment: Really? So, try to prove it! I have spent on it a few days and I really cannot to do it.

Comment: Your answer is not good, because this ball exist in the space Y, we have to find a ball in the space X!

Comment: $Y \subset X$, so the ball lives also in $X$...

Comment: Yes, but a ball in the space X may be bigger than the ball in the space Y with the same radius! and then we don't know if inclusion $B\subset V$ is still true for the bigger ball! I have got a right solution on some Polish forum, it is not so simple. I'm sure that your solution is bad :)

Comment: What ? That is nonsense. The fact that $\mathrm{Int}(Y_n)$ is open tells you that there is a ball in it, that is a set like $\lbrace x \in X \text{ }| \text{ } d(a,x) < r \rbrace$ for some $a \in Y_n$ and $r > 0$. This ball is a ball, and it does not depend in which set you are considering it !

Comment: By the way, I am sure of my solution, even if I would not call "solution" the answer of such a tautological problem.

Comment: No!, we know that  $\{x\in Y:d(a,x)<r\}\subset V$ but it does not imply that $\{x\in X:d(a,x)<r\}\subset V$ because we have inclusion $\{x\in Y:d(a,x)<r\}\subset \{x\in X:d(a,x)<r\}$

Comment: Because $V$ is open in $Y$, not in $X$. This is simple :)

Comment: Do you mean that the "interior" of $Y_n$ is the interior relatively to the induced topology of $Y$ ?

Comment: Yes, I have written that $V$ is open in $Y$, not in $X$

Comment: So which statement do you want to prove ? The first one with $V$, or the second one with $Y_n$ ? I guess it's a mix of both...

Comment: This is the same, but have solution already from some Polish page. You can see the solution of AlexL. His solution is the same.

Comment: No it is not the same. The second one is obviously false if you don't suppose that $Y$ is the closure of an open set. By the way, AlexL gave you a trivial answer...

Comment: But I have assumed that $Y$ is the closure of an open set.

Comment: In the first statement, yes. Not in the second one.

Comment: Please read more precisely :) I have wrote that we know ALSO that :)

Comment: I read precisely when it is readable. Here there is a $V$, then the $V$ disappears, and there are $Y_n$. I can't understand anything.

Comment: AlexL can understand :) $V$ and $int Y_N$ are the same

Comment: So why do you give them different names ??? The most basic thing at maths is to be clear with the objects. Obviously you are making a lot of confusions, that's why you are not suceeding in solving such easy questions.

Comment: Yes, maybe formulation of my question is not clear. I'm sorry :) and thank you!

Comment: I can't comment on this answer because I don't know what the Q was before the proposer re-wrote it. But in the present form of the Q we must use the assumption that  $A$ is open in $X.$ For example, if $X=\Bbb R$ and $ A=Y=\{0\}$  then $A$ is $not$ open in $X$ and no non-empty open ball of $X$ is a subset of $Y.$